# Refactor your code to get this URI from a customizable parameter in Swift project for Sonarqube

Tags: swift, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am working on an iOS project, For code quality/coverage checking I have set up Sonarqube into my project. It is a good library to check code quality.

It is running successfully and we have fixed most of the issues too.
And for API URLs we have declared in some constant classes and calling each one to the corresponding class.
But, Sonarqube throwing the following error for that, and I cannot understand that for resolve.

`SomeConstant.Swift`

```
import Foundation

struct SomeConstant {
    static let signInURL = "https://somesigninurl.com"
    static let signUpURL = "https://somesignuprl.com"
    static let baseURL = "https://somebaseurl.com"
    static let dashBoard = ""\(baseurl)"/dashboard/"
}
```

Error

> Refactor your code to get this URI from a customizable parameter.

Their documentation gave the following solution, But I am not getting why they call encoding and all other things. So, I did get properly understand below code

How to resolve this, Any suggestions?

```
public class Foo {
    // Configuration is a class that returns customizable properties: it can be mocked to be injected during tests.
    private var config:Configuration
    public init(myConfig:Configuration) {
        config = myConfig
    }
    public func listUsers() -> [User] {
        var users:[User]
        // Find here the way to get the correct folder, in this case using the Configuration object
        let location = config.getProperty("myApplication.listingFile")
        // and use this parameter instead of the hard coded path
        let fileContent = NSString(contentsOfFile: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        users = parse(fileContent!)
        return users
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check the [documentation](https://rules.sonarsource.com/swift/RSPEC-1075?search=hardcoded%20uri) of that particular Sonarqube code smell? It clearly shows how to resolve the code smell.

Comment: @DávidPásztor thanks for the link, I have updated my query, But I am not getting what they are suggesting since its just url

Answer (score 1):

`Refactor your code to get this URI from a customizable parameter.` means that you have to read your data from customizable source, e.g. config file:

ConfigFile.txt:

```
signInURL = "https://somesigninurl.com"
signUpURL = "https://somesignuprl.com"
baseURL = "https://somebaseurl.com"
dashBoard = ""\(baseurl)"/dashboard/"
```

**Pseudocode** for resolving your problem would be something like this:

```
import Foundation

struct SomeConstant {
    static let signInURL = config.getProperty("signInURL")
    static let signUpURL = config.getProperty("signUpURL")
    static let baseURL = config.getProperty("baseURL")
    static let dashBoard = config.getProperty("dashBoard")

    private var config:Configuration
    public init(myConfig:Configuration) {
        config = myConfig
    }   
}
```

As of

> But I am not getting why they call encoding and all other things

An example from Sonarqube documentation in non-compliant solution have encoding part while reading file content, from your question I will presume that you don't have it, so you can ignore it.

```
public class Foo {
    public func listUsers() -> [User] {
        var users:[User]
        let location = "/home/mylogin/Dev/users.txt"     // Non-Compliant
                                                             \/_____HERE_YOU_GO_____________
        let fileContent = NSString(contentsOfFile: location, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
        users = parse(fileContent!)
        return users
    }
}
```